# Removing Prospective Search from an Android App based on Mobile Backend Starter

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My android app is inserting records into the google cloud datastore but after each insertion, I am seeing:

12:24:32.836 200 0 B 7 ms /_ah/prospective_search

I would like to stop the app doing this but I am struggling to work out how.

I was assuming this is actioned somewhere in the com.google.cloud.backend code but I cannot find it or any reference to prospective search or any of the functions in that API (subscribe(), etc.)

Does anyone know how to remove this functionality or what bits of java I should be searching for in the android app code?

Comment: The reference docs are at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.prospective_search.prospective_search -- list_subscriptions to get your current subscriptions, unsubscribe on each (both on the app engine side of things of course). Or, just wait for prospective search to disappear on Dec 1, just 2 weeks from now, per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/prospective_search .

Comment: ok, so you're saying this isn't something the app is doing. It's a function of the app-engine. I'll have a look there and come back. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, prospective search is an App Engine feature (currently deprecated, and due to be removed on Dec 1, per the URL I gave above). Your App Engine app can list your prospective search subscriptions and unsubscribe from them, though, with just 2 weeks to go, you might perhaps not care.

Comment: ok thanks. I was wondering if it would break my system when Google removed this feature which is why i asked the initial question. If it just stops using it (and I don't really use it AFAIK) then it sounds all good.